# RSpec test is written in 2 ways and one of them fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I have this RSpec test - it passes correctly:

```
 it "should have the right title" do
  page.should { have_selector('title', 
                            :text => "#{base_title}") }
end
```

I am trying to re-write the same piece of code like this:

```
    it { should have_selector('title', 
                          :text => "#{base_title}") }
```

**but the shorter code fails.**
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that I forgot to add before that statement:

```
subject { page }
```

Comment: seems as if we are at the same page in the tutorial ;-)